# Extjs 4 grid filtering

Tags: plugins, extjs, filter, grid

this is exactly what I am looking for http://www.developerextensions.com/index.php/extjs-filter-row but I could not find a version which would work well with extjs 4

Its very possible that I created a false code because I am noobie in extjs so could you please help me with this or some similar extension how exactly to implement it and make it work?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 11):

You don't need to use external plugins. In Ext JS 4.1 filtering can be done easily without any plugins.

There are nice examples of both local and remote filtering in documentation.

1. [Remote filtering](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example/grid/infinite-scroll-with-filter.html)
2. [Local filtering](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example/grid-filtering/grid-filter-local.html)

Comment: The first example looks good. Thank you 

how do you create for each individual column a separate search box / filter box?

I am really new to extjs syntax

Answer (score 3):

Here is a grid plugin that adds filtering row below grid header. Allows remote filtering and supports pagination grids.

https://github.com/roberto-rodriguez/ExtJs_GridFilterPlugin

It works pretty well in Ext version 4.

Here is an image of what it does:

[image]

Comment: While I greatly appreciate your effort, I have not worked for the company that required this solution for 4 years. Hopefully they figured another way sooner.