# Extjs filters on grid column not working?

Tags: extjs

I am trying to add filters in ext grid column but its not working, Help will be greatly appreciated.

Below is the grid code.

```
{
xtype : 'gridpanel',
border: false,
title : 'Users',
store : Store,
features: [{
            ftype : 'filters',
            paramPrefix : 'filterParam',
            autoReload : false,
            local : false,
            showMenu: false,
            filters:[{
                type: 'string',
                dataIndex: 'value'
            }] 
}],
columns: [
    {text: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'value', flex: 1, filterable: 'true',
         items: {
             xtype: 'textfield',
             name: 'value',
             width : '100%',
             align: 'center',
             margin: '0 2 2 2'}
         },
    {text: 'GID',  dataIndex: 'key'}],

height: '100%',
width: '100%',   
}
```

I tried by adding below code also on top of above code but no luck.

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true,
    paths: {
        'Ext.ux': './ext/ux'
    }
});
Ext.require(['Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature']);
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working ?

Comment: Filters are not filtering records from grid. If I type in textbox then it should display filtered records in Grid..

Comment: I had some trouble with them too. And they are no longer supported in ExtJs 5. I found a nice solution for filtering. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22014855/extjs-filter-a-grid-with-a-search-field-in-the-column-header