# Make filters appear above column ExtJs 4.1.3

Tags: javascript, xml, extjs

I have filters activated on each column in this ExtJs panel grid that appear as drop downs for each column. Is there a way to make them appear automatically above each corresponding column?

[Desired outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWIfV.jpg)

[fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/238v)

Comment: Not sure what axectly you want? Show filtering options for all columns on click on any column header?

Comment: @SergeyNovikov I added a more clarifying picture. I'd like the filter input to appear above each column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some ideas here: [ExtJs - Filter a grid with a search field in the column header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22014855/extjs-filter-a-grid-with-a-search-field-in-the-column-header)

Basically you can add a text field as a sub component in the items of a column config. In that linked example they use [Ext.form.field.Trigger](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Trigger).

Then add a listener on that field for whatever event you want to trigger the filter. In your handler, get a reference to the store and manually filter it as needed based on the text field input.